# JQuery on click has no action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple controll with jquery that should show an alert onclick if username and password are not empty.

Actually i've tryed the following code for jquery but it has no effect, no any response in console, nothing.

```html
<label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." autofocus="autofocus" />

<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." />


<input type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-fill btn-block mb-3" value="Login" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
    if (!$('#username').val() && !$('#password').val()) {
      alert("VAI!");
    }
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**
here is full code of the page, in codebehind there is nothing, seems that the javascript just dies when executing the function click.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="auth.aspx.vb" Inherits="servizigab.auth" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Gab Servizi: Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/css/modalstyle.css" type="text/css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/css/login.css" type="text/css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

<body class="text-center fade-in">
    <form class="form-signin" runat="server">


        <img class="mb-2" draggable="false" src="assets/img/gabservizi.png" alt="" width="160" height="160" />

        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal" translate="yes">Accedi a Gab Servizi!</h1>
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." autofocus="autofocus" />

        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." />


        <input type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-fill btn-block mb-3" value="Login"/>

        <p class="text-muted mt-2 mb-3">Non hai un profilo? <a href="#" class="text-primary">Richiedilo!</a></p>


        <div class="myAlert-bottom alert alert-danger">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Password o nome utente errati!</strong> Riprovare!
        </div>

        <iframe id="log" class="d-none"/>

    </form>

                        <!-- librerie js -->
    <script src="/assets/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
    if ($('#username').val() && $('#password').val()) {
      alert("VAI!");
    }
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine (or at least does what you say it should do) when I test it.

Comment: @Quentin https://gyazo.com/3dbc517ca1b8ce5d46941a2f370d4b63 check the gif

Comment: It is working fine

Comment: Check your developer console tool, there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: @Sushil if not empty

Comment: You likely want to test differently `if ($('#username').val() && $('#password').val()) {
      alert("VAI!");
    } else { alert("NO!"); }`

Comment: As Quentin put, it your only problem is that you had your logic backwards. Just remove your `!`s. [Here's a live demo with the changes.](http://jsfiddle.net/stqpe6ho/3/)

Comment: Just added full code from the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem 1 Your logic is backwards

`!` means not.

So you are testing if they are *both* **empty** (i.e. There is not a value for username and there is not a value for password) and not that they both have values.

Remove the `!`s.

```html
<label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." autofocus="autofocus" />

<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." />


<input type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-fill btn-block mb-3" value="Login" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
    if ($('#username').val() && $('#password').val()) {
      alert("VAI!");
    }
  });
</script>
```

## Problem 2: Your HTML is invalid

Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/). It will tell you that your `<iframe>` is missing its end tag. This puts all the content that follows it (including the script) **inside the iframe** so the script is treated as alternative content for browsers that don't support iframes and is not executed.

Comment: Actually i can't get what is wrong i'm uploading a video but even without ! nothing has changed

Comment: @JohnKarry — Works fine in the live demo in my answer.

Comment: yeah in the demo works for me too but in the site it doesn't.. just check here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0FCbcVmnBs

Comment: @JohnKarry — Then you must have some other problem, which isn't expressed in your question, and you need to create a [mcve] which demonstrates *that* problem.

Comment: @JohnKarry — You should provide an [mcve] in the question itself. (In this case the problem would be revealed by the use of [a validator](https://validator.nu/)) (hmm, the comment I thought I saw linking to JS Fiddle seems to have vanished, this comment refers to that).

Comment: i just updated the question with whole code, actually i think that the click function kills in someway the javascript as even alert() on button click doesn't work if the function where i check the username and psw is in code

Comment: @JohnKarry — No. As I said before, the problem is that your HTML is invalid.

Comment: i was just going mad, that solved as well, thank you. Tought that wouldn't create problems by closing iframe with /> at the end.

Comment: HTML isn't XML. You can't close an element by putting `/` at the end of a start tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use strings `length` property:

```html
<label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." autofocus="autofocus" />

<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." />


<input type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-fill btn-block mb-3" value="Login" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
    //check if both the username and password values have
    // lengths grater then zero
    if ($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0) {
      alert("VAI!");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Or just delete the `!` (not) sign from your own code.

Comment: This is just another way to do it - it doesn't mean the question is wrong that one works too.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to bind your events in $(document).ready if you have lots of other javascript code on page. your code works perfectly if there is no other javascript code.

Just bind click event in $(document).ready as shown below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
    if ($('#username').val() && $('#password').val()) {
      alert("VAI!");
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." autofocus="autofocus" />
<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." />
<input type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-fill btn-block mb-3" value="Login" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it will work.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It's possibly a best practise (but that's a matter of opinion) but won't solve the problem.

Comment: Well, it is a very simple code that should work, we all know. If it is not working it clearly indicates that control is not reaching the script block which binds click event, so there is no action when user clicks login. $(document).ready will make sure to execute this code block. So In my opinion it should solve the problem

Comment: Since the script block isn't being executed at all, putting different code inside the script block won't solve the problem. Your answer would solve the problem "The JS is trying to bind to the element before it was created" but the question said "The code is placed before body close tag."

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($('#username').val() && $('#password').val()) {
```